# Does Rakshasas belongs to human species?

Tags: rakshasa, human

Is Rakshasa a separate species or a group of people in human species?

I mean, does Rakshasa means a bad/immoral human or entirely different from human species? Rakshasa

Comment: Rakshasa is a different species

Comment: Devatas and Rakshasas have common progeny of human race (Kashyapa). Not following tenets of same Dharma sets the one from the other apart in a long process of evolution... between good and evil traits.

Comment: @Narasimham They are definitely not human. They are not descended from the first human, and way, way too big. In the Kali Purana for example a five year old Rakshasa is big enough to have a garland of elephants. I don't anyone could read the 16th chapter of the of the Kalki Purana and think Rakshasa are human. https://cloudup.com/cws97nPY2uD

Comment: सुर, दैत्य, दानव, राक्षस सभी ऋषि कश्यप की संताने थीं !
पौराणिक कथाओं के अनुसार दानवों और राक्षसों का आपस में काफी पुराना बैर चला आ रहा था, इसी के चलते राक्षसराज रावण ने अपने ही बहनोई दानव विद्युतजिह्वा का वध कर दिया था। आम धारणा और बोलचाल में असुर, दानव, दैत्य और राक्षसों को तकरीबन एक जैसा ही माना जाता है। Kashyap's children all.. common ancestry but enmity and different standards of Dharma.